# Memory leak in UIApplication

Tags: iphone

getting memory leak object **NSDate** and responsible library is UIKit responsible frame is **UIApplication:sendAction:to:from:forEvent:** why is that. How can i fix this memory leak. I am not using interface builder at all. All is done programmatically

```
Event Type  Responsible Library Responsible Caller
Malloc      UIKit                   [UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
Autorelease UIKit                   [UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
Retain      UIKit                   [UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
Release     Foundation           [NSAutoreleasePool release]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't mind if Instruments says that the responsible library is UIKit. That only means that the actual allocation of memory was done inside UIKit, but I am almost sure that the responsibility for the leak is in your code. This is almost my experience with memory leaks that Instruments/Xcode finds with responsible library being an SDK framework.

My suggestion is checking which NSDate you are allocating and making sure that they are all released. Sometimes, the objects that are leaked are only indirectly related to the type that Instruments reports.

In the end the most effective way to discover a leak cause is to inspect the code that is executed when instruments show you the leak (which view were you using? which task? etc.)

Without seeing your code, nothing more precise can be said, I fear.

EDIT:

looking at your code, I would suggest that you check what happens when you do:

```
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
```

if `pauseStart` is referencing an object, then assigning to it like this will produce a leak, because you lose the reference to the previous object; you could do:

```
[pauseStart release];
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
```

or better

```
self.pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
```

(I assume here the `pauseStart` is kind of retain property).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i can give you little hint that using pauseTimer and resumeTimer (void)pauseTimer{
    pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
    previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
    [timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
-(void)resumeTimer{
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
//[timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
} rleased pauseStart andpreviousFireDate in dealloc method

Comment: i tried both self.pauseStart as well as pauseStart release. still memory leak on UIApplication send to.....event

Comment: what kind (retain/assign) of property is it? are you calling `invalidate` somewhere on the timer?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *pauseStart;
- (void)stop: (id) sender

{
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [timer invalidate];
    MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];   
}

Comment: I see. A good technique to isolate the origin of the leak is selectively comment out parts of the code. It is not always possible, of course, but, eg., what happens if you refactor your code so not to use pauseTimer? so to not to use the timers (or use it just once)? the app will not work as it should, but is the leak there?